# In MS Word 2010, how do I use different styles for different indexes?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles

I'm using the \f switch in Microsoft Word 2010 to create multiple indexes. I need to style these indexes differently from one another, but I'm unable to work out how to apply different styles to these different indexes (Word seems to insist both indexes use "Index 1", "Index 2" and so on). I can, of course, manually apply styles after creating the index, but then I have to re-do it everytime I update the index, which I want to avoid. Does anyone know if it's possible?